# How Can I add a user of type jobber to another user Favorite List using Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, favorites

I am working on the add to favorites and view favorites list functionality on my website.
I have managed to create 2 tables

> A users tables with id, name, surname, photo, type and email
>
> A favorites tables with id, user_id, favoriteable_id, created_at and updated_at

I was trying to implement it in such a way that when a user, who is connected to his account clicks on the add to favorites button, It will add the user selected on his list of favorites.

I tried doing it this way but it didn't quite worked and got confused in the process.

This is my web routes

```
Route::post('favorite/{user}', 'FavoriteController@favoriteUser')->name('jobber.fav.store');
Route::post('unfavorite/{user}', 'Favorite@unFavoriteUser');
Route::get('my_favorites', 'UsersController@myFavorites')->middleware('auth');
```

This is my Favorite Controller

```
   /**
 * Favorite a particular jobber
 *
 * @param  User $user
 * @return Response
 */
public function favoriteUser(User $user)
{
    Auth::user()->favorites()->attach($user->id);

    return back();
}

/**
 * Unfavorite a particular post
 *
 * @param  User $user
 * @return Response
 */
public function unFavoriteUser(User $user)
{
    Auth::user()->favorites()->detach($user->id);

    return back();
}
```

and this is my User Controller

```
 /**
 * Get all favorite posts by user
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function myFavorites()
{
    $myFavorites = Auth::user()->favorites;

    return view('users.my_favorites', compact('myFavorites'));
}
```

And the route that adds to the list of favorites

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <a class="apply-thisjob" href="#" title=""><i class="la la-paper-plane"></i>Recherchez d'autres jobbeurs</a>
                                    
<a class="add-tofavorite" href=" {{ route('jobber.fav.store', ['id'=>$result->id]) }}" title=""><i class="la la-heart-o"></i>Add to my favorites</a>

                                </div>
```

And this is my_favorites.blade.php

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <div class="page-header">
            <h3>My Favorites</h3>
        </div>
        @forelse ($myFavorites as $myFavorite)
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    {{ $myFavorite->name}}
                </div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    {{ $myFavorite->photo}}
                </div>
               
            </div>
        @empty
            <p>You have no favorite posts.</p>
        @endforelse
     </div>
```

and Inside my user Model I added this

```
public function favorites()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Favorite::class, 'favorites', 'user_id', 'favoriteable_id')->withTimeStamps();
}
```

And this is my favorite model

```
 public function user() 
{
return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Can Anyone help me out? Or any suggestions on how to make it work.. THanks in advance.

Comment: You got quite some mistakes in your code, which can be a lot to point out until it works. So my suggestions would be that you look into some existing alternatives like the [laravel-favorite](https://github.com/ChristianKuri/laravel-favorite) package. It will not only do exactly what you want, it also allows you to favorite any model with the same database table. In your case you would have to use both traits, `Favoriteability` and `Favoriteable` on the `User` model. One important mistake is that you used the wrong controller in `Route::post('unfavorite/{user}', 'Favorite@unFavoriteUser');`.

Comment: Ok I see. I will search videos on that package

Comment: But it's still possible to do it manually without installing a package? because most tutorials I saw tried to do it manually.